# Port size error in Verilog: [PCDPC] - Port size does not match connection size (1) for port

Tags: verilog

These are my codes for different parts of single cycle processor but i am getting following warnings in instantiation. Kindly help me in finding this mistake because this mistake occurs so often

```
 module reg_file(reg_addr_1,reg_addr_2,write_en,RD1,RD2,write_data,reg_addr_1,reg_addr_2,clk,wr_addr);
input clk;
input[3:0] reg_addr_1,reg_addr_2;
input [3:0] wr_addr;
input [15:0]write_data;
input write_en;
output [15:0]RD1,RD2;
reg [15:0]rgs[0:15];

assign RD1=rgs[reg_addr_1];
assign R22=rgs[reg_addr_2];

always@(posedge clk)
begin
if(write_en)
rgs[wr_addr] <= write_data;
end
endmodule





module alu(cout,alu_output,input1,input2,alu_sel);
input [15:0]input1,input2;
input [3:0]alu_sel;
output [15:0]alu_output;
output cout;
reg [15:0]alu_output;
reg cout;
always@(input1,input2,alu_sel)
begin
case(alu_sel)
4'b0000 : {cout,alu_output}=input1+input2;
4'b0001 : {cout,alu_output}=input1-input2;
4'b0010 : alu_output=input2-1;
4'b0011 : alu_output=input1*input2;
4'b0100 : alu_output=input1&&input2;
4'b0101 : alu_output=input1||input2;
4'b0110 : alu_output= !input1;
4'b0111 : alu_output=~input1;
4'b1000 : alu_output=input1&input2;
4'b1001 : alu_output=input1|input2;
4'b1010 : alu_output=input1^input2;
4'b1011 : alu_output=input1<<1;
4'b1100 : alu_output=input1>>1;
4'b1101 : alu_output=input1+1;
4'b1110 : alu_output=input1-1;
4'b1111 : alu_output=input2<<1;
endcase 
end  
endmodule




module reg_alu(clk,out);
input clk;
output [15:0] out;

alu a1(cout,out,RD1,RD2,alu_sel);
reg_file a2(reg_addr_1,reg_addr_2,write_en,RD1,RD2,alu_output,reg_addr_1,reg_addr_2,clk,wr_addr);
endmodule






module tb_aaaa;
reg clk;
wire alu_output;
wire [15:0]out;
reg write_en;
reg [15:0]input1,input2;
reg [3:0]alu_sel;
reg_alu tb_aaaa(clk,out);
initial 
begin
#10 clk=1'b1;write_en=1'b0;input1=16'b0000000101010101;input2=16'b0000000000111111;alu_sel=4'b0010;
#10 clk=1'b0;write_en=1'b1;input2=16'b0000000101010101;input2=16'b0000000000111100;alu_sel=4'b0011;
end
initial begin
$monitor($time,"clk,out,write_data",clk,out);
end
initial
begin
#300 $stop;
end
endmodule
```

These are the warnings i am getting from compiler

```
     ** Warning: (vsim-3015) C:/Users/Saeed/Desktop/project/reg_alu.v(5): [PCDPC] - Port size (16 or 16) does not match connection size (1) for port 'input1'.
    #         Region: /tb_aaaa/tb_aaaa/a1
    # ** Warning: (vsim-3015) C:/Users/Saeed/Desktop/project/reg_alu.v(5): [PCDPC] - Port size (16 or 16) does not match connection size (1) for port 'input2'.
    #         Region: /tb_aaaa/tb_aaaa/a1
    # ** Warning: (vsim-3015) C:/Users/Saeed/Desktop/project/reg_alu.v(5): [PCDPC] - Port size (4 or 4) does not match connection size (1) for port 'alu_sel'.
    #         Region: /tb_aaaa/tb_aaaa/a1
    # ** Warning: (vsim-3015) C:/Users/Saeed/Desktop/project/reg_alu.v(6): [PCDPC] - Port size (4 or 4) does not match connection size (1) for port 'reg_addr_1'.
    #         Region: /tb_aaaa/tb_aaaa/a2
    # ** Warning: (vsim-3015) C:/Users/Saeed/Desktop/project/reg_alu.v(6): [PCDPC] - Port size (4 or 4) does not match connection size (1) for port 'reg_addr_2'.
    #         Region: /tb_aaaa/tb_aaaa/a2
    # ** Warning: (vsim-3015) C:/Users/Saeed/Desktop/project/reg_alu.v(6): [PCDPC] - Port size (16 or 16) does not match connection size (1) for port 'RD1'.
    #         Region: /tb_aaaa/tb_aaaa/a2
    # ** Warning: (vsim-3015) C:/Users/Saeed/Desktop/project/reg_alu.v(6): [PCDPC] - Port size (16 or 16) does not match connection size (1) for port 'RD2'.
    #         Region: /tb_aaaa/tb_aaaa/a2
    # ** Warning: (vsim-3015) C:/Users/Saeed/Desktop/project/reg_alu.v(6): [PCDPC] - Port size (16 or 16) does not match connection size (1) for port 'write_data'.
    #         Region: /tb_aaaa/tb_aaaa/a2
    # ** Warning: (vsim-3015) C:/Users/Saeed/Desktop/project/reg_alu.v(6): [PCDPC] - Port size (4 or 4) does not match connection size (1) for port 'reg_addr_1'.
    #         Region: /tb_aaaa/tb_aaaa/a2
    # ** Warning: (vsim-3015) C:/Users/Saeed/Desktop/project/reg_alu.v(6): [PCDPC] - Port size (4 or 4) does not match connection size (1) for port 'reg_addr_2'.
    #         Region: /tb_aaaa/tb_aaaa/a2
    # ** Warning: (vsim-3015) C:/Users/Saeed/Desktop/project/reg_alu.v(6): [PCDPC] - Port size (4 or 4) does not match connection size (1) for port 'wr_addr'.
    #         Region: /tb_aaaa/tb_aaaa/a2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your problems is that you are using wires without declaring their width. Verilog has a nasty behavior when you use a name without declaring it in a port connection, it assumes it is a one bit wire. This was fine when people were doing gate-level descriptions, and most wires were one bit, but not for RTL. So put this directive at the beginning of each file

```
`default_nettype none
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, actually I already found the critical mistake I was doing. I wasn't declaring my RD1 and RD2 as a wire hence they were sent as a output to the alu as wires. And i am working on remaining warnings that are actually because of my logic. Highly appreciate your reply. Thanks again Sir. Cheers